# Saving as CSV through google script handling newline characters

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm attempting to take a sheet from a Google Spreadsheet and save it as a .CSV file just like you can manually do. It is working fairly well, but I've ran into an issue with new lines/line feeds/carriage returns etc. I have used and modified [Google's solution](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial?csw=1) and some stack overflow resources that have meet my needs so far, however I'm stuck on this new line issue.

The Problem:
[image: Problem]

The Cause:
[image: Cause]

I will note that if I manually save the CSV file from Google Spreadsheets it looks fine, but that box you see in the cause picture is the issue I cannot resolve.

My current code:

```
function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
  // get available data range in the spreadsheet
  var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = activeRange.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            //Handle special characters
            var text = data[row][col].toString();

            text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g," ");
            for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
            {
              if(text[i] == "\'" || text[i] == "\"" || text[i] == "\\" || text[i] == "\n" || text[i] == "\r" || text[i] == "\t" || text[i] == "\b" || text[i] == "\f")
              {
                text = spliceSlice(text,i,0,"\\");
                i++;
              }
            }
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + text + "\""; //Puts quotes around the data for strings.
          }
        }

        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }

    }
    csvFile = csv;

    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm attempting to handle the new lines with what I have read about 'regex expressions' however, they don't seem to actually be doing anything for me. So perhaps I'm just using it wrong and then it will work, or I need to go about this differently.

**EDIT:** I've looked at the file in Notepad++ and determined that they are LF characters causing the problem in the middle of the rows. Where as my end of row \r\n is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g," ")` try `.replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ")`, I know it's essentially the same, but I'm currently using this solution without hiccups.

Comment: I attempted to use this instead and I'm having the same problem still.

Comment: After tinkering around with this some more, it ended up working. To be honest I don't know if your switch was what caused it, but I didn't do anything significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I ran into it at the top of my Google search when just looking for a simple solution to handling newlines on a CSV export from Sheets.

Since it's 2022 now, you can use Sheets' pretty powerful find + replace to target all newline characters (removing them, or replacing them with a literal `\n` string, etc). You can then export as CSV normally.

[image]

In my example here, the "Replace with" doesn't use regex, only the search does, so I'm wanting to preserve the newlines here before export.