# GAS replace comma with tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a simple app to take the content from one,or a few, row(s) and output a text file. I have 2 questions (see below code snippet):

```
function saveAsTSV3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = s.getRange("A53:HY54");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var text = values.join('\r\n');
  regex = new RegExp(',','g');
  text = text.replace(regex,'\t');
  DriveApp.createFile("A file.tsv", text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

It does create the file and put it in the right folder.

1. But, it is filled with commas instead of tab characters.
    **2. Similarly, I need a line-break character at the end of each row. Presently it puts everything together into one long row.**

Anyone know how to do these two things?  Any assistance is much appreciated!

[Here is a sample spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yuwL80cmI7NMuzG5tt9FOYQDbTR3_U_tDacBqJ0OOY4)

Comment: Are you looking that the column separator be a tab instead of a comma?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getValues return a JavaScript array. One way to get the desired result is

- to join the values of the unique row by using `\n` or `\r\n` as line separator.
- replace the commas inserted by the previous step by usen `replace` with the `g` modificator.
- to create the file by using MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT instead of MimeType.CSV as the last is intended for comma separated values files.

The code will be similar to the following snipeet:

```
function saveAsTSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = s.getRange("A1:C6");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var end_of_line = '\n';
  var text = values.join(end_of_line);
  regex = new RegExp(',','g');
  text = text.replace(regex,'\t');
  DriveApp.createFile("A file.tsv", text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

NOTE: According to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115554/1595451) `\n` is the end of line for UNIX systems, `\r\n` for Windows systems. Another answer on the same Q&A thread refers to https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/

Related:

- [Saving as CSV through google script handling newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29135248/1595451)

Comment: Thank you. That successfully separated the columns into tabs.  Do you know how to separate each row with a break.  It may be something like /n.

Comment: Ok, I hope I have further clarified #2 in my original question.  I am not sure how to further describe the problem.

Comment: For some reason, the line-break is two positions too late.  In the exported file, Row2 begins with Column C.  Thus, the two rows don't line up in the exported file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157765/discussion-between-neill-and-ruben).

Comment: I got it!  It is  var text = values.join('\r\n');

Comment: @Neil: The required line separator could vary depending on the target system. I updated my answer.